# How to log all the API request made by Redux-Toolkit Query?

Tags: redux, rtk-query

I need to log all the API calls made by Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query.

I know we can use `redux-logger` for logging all the state changes to console for development purpose, but I need to log all the state changes/API calls made by RTK Query.

I see RTK Query uses `fetch` under the hood and so cannot have an interceptor to do the job. Neither do I want to replace fetch with axios library to introduce an interceptor.

Another option I am not going for is to override the `console.log` of windows to do the logging to server end point.

I see there are similar things provided by log rocket, but I am not wanting to onboard to that either.

What are my options here?

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import logger from 'redux-logger'

import { rootReducer } from 'src/reducers/rootReducer';

const otherMiddlewares: any[] = [];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === `development`) {
    otherMiddlewares.push(logger);
}

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    // The API slice generates a custom middleware which
    // manages cache lifetimes and expiration
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
      getDefaultMiddleware().concat(otherMiddlewares)
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Answer (score 1):

In RTK Query, you would not use an interceptor like in axios, but you would wrap the `baseQuery` function:

```
const originalBaseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ /* your config */ })
const wrappedBaseQuery = (...args) => {
  console.log ("making api call", ...args)
  return originalBaseQuery (...args)
}

createApi({
  baseQuery: wrappedBaseQuery ,
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One way i can think of to log all the redux changes is to write a middle ware for custom logging

````
  // Log the current state and action being dispatched
  logger.info("Current State:", store.getState());
  logger.info("Action:", action);

  // Call the next middleware in the chain
  const result = next(action);

  // Log the new state after the action has been processed
  logger.info("New State:", store.getState());

  // Return the result of the next middleware in the chain
  return result;
};

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import loggerMiddleware from "./middleware/logger";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(loggerMiddleware)
);```
````